# Call a stored procedure to insert to SQL Server database from Flask API

Tags: python, sql-server, rest

I am trying to call my SQL Server stored procedure to insert a new customer from my Flask API. Result from the SQL profiler shows the data is reaching the database but the customer is not created

Here is my API endpoint code:

```py
@app.route('/Customer',methods=['POST'])
@validate()
def add_customer():
    args=customer_args.parse_args()
    name=args['Name']
    addr=args['Addr']
    phone1=args['Phone1']
    phone2=args['Phone2']
    mobile=args['Mobile']
    town=args['Town']
    email=args['EmailAddress']
    vat=args['VATNO']
    pin=args['PIN']
    notes = args['Notes']
    cat=args['CatID']
    location=args['Location']
    if name:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        sql = "exec dbo.InsertCustomer @CustName=?,@CustAddr=?,@Phone1=?,@Phone2=?," \
                "@Mobile=?,@Town=?,@EmailAddress=?,@VATNO=?,@PIN=?,@NOTES=?,@CatID=?,@Location=?"
        con=cursor.execute(sql, (name, addr, phone1, phone2, mobile, town, email, vat, pin, notes, cat, location))
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        if con:
            return {"message": "Success"}, 201
        return {"message": "failed"}, 400
    return "Values not provided"
```

And here is the results from SQL profiler:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=1
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 nvarchar(14),@P2 nvarchar(22),@P3 nvarchar(20),@P4 nvarchar(18),@P5 nvarchar(22),@P6 nvarchar(26),@P7 nvarchar(36),@P8 nvarchar(26),@P9 nvarchar(24),@P10 nvarchar(30),@P11 nvarchar(2),@P12 nvarchar(12)',N'exec dbo.InsertCustomer @CustName=@P1,@CustAddr=@P2,@Phone1=@P3,@Phone2=@P4,@Mobile=@P5,@Town=@P6,@EmailAddress=@P7,@VATNO=@P8,@PIN=@P9,@NOTES=@P10,@CatID=@P11,@Location=@P12',N'ndackia',N'byaghqdsssf',N'23456214sf',N'123452446',N'wty34vdvsff',N'kisumudgfegfs',N'mskcndksdnckefeegt',N'rt56ubscfsdee',N'trygvh5sfsfs',N'ghjbknlmlsfdasf',N'4',N'kisumu'
select @p1
```

This is the code for procedure dbo.InsertCustomer
**

```
USE [cec_GESA]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertCustomer]    Script Date: 6/27/2021 4:40:17 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertCustomer]
    @CustName NVARCHAR(100),
    @CustAddr NVARCHAR(70),
    @Phone1 NVARCHAR(25) = '',
    @Phone2 NVARCHAR(25) = '',
    @Mobile NVARCHAR(25) = '',
    @Town NVARCHAR(20) = '',
    @Fax NVARCHAR(15) = '',
    @EmailAddress NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @VATNO NVARCHAR(12) = '',
    @PIN NVARCHAR(15) = '',
    @NOTES NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @CatID INT = 2,
    @CreditLimit NUMERIC(18, 2) = 0,
    @SalesRep INT = NULL,
    @Latitude FLOAT = NULL,
    @Longitude FLOAT = NULL,
    @Location NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Terms INT = 0,
    @SendUpdates NVARCHAR(25) = NULL,
    @Active BIT = 1,
    @Rating INT = 1
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
               CustName
        FROM dbo.Customer
        WHERE CustName = @CustName
    )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Customer
        (
            --CustID,
            CustName,
            CustAddr,
            Phone1,
            Phone2,
            Mobile,
            Town,
            Fax,
            EmailAddress,
            VATNO,
            PIN,
            NOTES,
            CatID,
            CreditLimit,
            SalesRep,
            Latitude,
            Longitude,
            Location,
            Terms,
            SendUpdates,
            Active,
            Rating
        )
        VALUES
        (
            --(SELECT ISNULL(MAX(CustID), 1) + 1 FROM Customer (NOLOCK)), 
            @CustName, @CustAddr, @Phone1, @Phone2, @Mobile, @Town, @Fax, @EmailAddress, @VATNO, @PIN, @NOTES, @CatID,
            @CreditLimit, @SalesRep, @Latitude, @Longitude, @Location, @Terms, @SendUpdates, @Active,
            @Rating);
            
        UPDATE dbo.Customer
        SET Account = dbo.CreateAccountNo(@CustName, (SELECT CustID FROM dbo.Customer WHERE CustName = @CustName))
        WHERE CustID =
        (
            SELECT CustID FROM dbo.Customer WHERE CustName = @CustName
        );
        SELECT MAX(CustID) FROM dbo.Customer;
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 0;
    END;
END;
```

**

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is the SQL code for the procedure `dbo.InsertCustomer`?

Comment: @Charlieface I have included the missing code

Comment: This procedure is rather interesting and has a number of issues: it looks for a matching `CustName` (note that `EXISTS` does not require `TOP 1`) and if it finds it then nothing is done. Otherwise it inserts, then creates an account using a *function* (functions are not meant to do inserts) and grabs `CustId` *twice* from the table rather than using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, then selects out the `MAX(Id)` (again should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` which may or may not be the correct one. How do you know the customer is not inserted, how are you verifying that?

Comment: am verifying by querying all the customers,if i execute the procedure on sql management studio and do a query to fetch all customers,the inserted customer is present which is not the case when i execute the procedure inside the Flask API

Comment: You sure there is no error? You sure you are connecting to the right server and database? You are not using `AttachDbFileName` in the connection string? I also suggest you switch on auto-commit (it's not the Python default for some reason)

Comment: Am using the same connection to call other procedures that fetches data from the same database and its working fine,but for some reason the procedures for updating and inserting are not working.Is there any other way i can call them in python